# Angular stacktrace in Firefox with Firebug

Tags: angularjs, firefox, firebug, console.log

I'm developing a webapp in Angular and I'm using Firefox with Firebug for debugging.

Whenever there is an error in my Angular, it fails to properly display the stacktrace. Instead it shows something like this in the console.log:

[image]

In Chrome, I get a nice stacktrace with a clickable link to the error definition:

[image]

Am I forced to switch to Chrome for developing in Angular, or is there a fix for this?

Comment: you get html link because you are using minimized version of angular js

Comment: I'm okay with getting a link, my problem is how it's formatted in firefox.

Answer (score 5):

Try to replace the minified version of Angular with the non-minified one.
If it is an injection problem, you will have more meaningful feedback in the console.
As more general answer, the best tools to debug angular are [AngularJS Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk) and [ng-inspector](http://ng-inspector.org/) and, yes, they are Chrome extensions.

Comment: Looks like the only thing that can be done is indeed using the non-minified version of angular, short of developing a firefox plugin myself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a singular add-on for firefox called **[AngScope](https://addons.mozilla.org/es/firefox/addon/angscope-simple-angularjs-s/)**, which is non-official, but appears to be very helpful when debugging angular.js in firefox. If you do not want to switch to chrome, it is worth trying.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of replacing angular.min.js with angular.js, you can make both files available along with angular.min.js.map. Firefox will recognize the source map file and pull the better error message and stack trace from the non-minified source.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to switch to Chrome's Developer Tools for better stack tracing. However, there may be a plugin/extension for Firefox that cleans things up for you so make sure you do a bit of research before making a decision.

But when comparing vanilla to vanilla, Chrome is what you want.

Comment: I can't find any plugins for this. I tried AngScope, but that only helps inspecting the angular $scope in the DOM.

Comment: Which is the same as Chrome's Batarang. I spent some time looking around, too, and it seems that Chrome just has a better developed tool for inspecting and tracing the stack. Most of the time, the differences are negligible but if you're going to be developing Angular apps, it appears that Chrome is going to make your life easier.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the same clickable feature to error link definition in Firebug, when you include angular.js to your web application. Firebug can capable to display line numbers(in which part error occured) for your Angular application.